# CodeIgniter base_url() for href and getcwd() for file_exists()

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I generalise or neutralise the difference between `base_url()` and `getcwd()`?

In a view, I want to display both an inline PDF-viewer (using the `<object src=''></object>`) and the OCR'ed output. Both of these require the same source file, which is located in `project/public/corpus/<some_id>/file.pdf` (where `project` is the CodeIgniter root).

The code in the controller can be summarised like this:

```
    /**
     * Fetch the path to the pdf of the document (OCR is preferred)
     * $handle is a unique identifier
     */
    $object_src = base_url("public/mi-corpus/" . $handle . "/file.pdf");

    $ocr_src = getcwd()."/public/mi-corpus/" . $handle . "/file.pdf";

    // Returns an <object> node from the source
    $this->data['object'] = $this->get_pdf($ocr_src);

    // uses a cloud OCR to parse the source and return OCR'ed text, this is irrelevant. But it does use file_exists($src) to check if the path is valid.
    $this->data['ocr'] = $this->mipreprocessing->open_ocr($ocr_src);
```

The thing is, when using `base_url()`, the function `file_exists($src)` always fails, but the `getcwd()` concatenation fails when producing a `src` attribute for the HTML `<object>`.

I see that `base_url()` yields a 'real' URL-like string ("http://localhost/" etc.), whereas `getcwd()` yields the actual path on the machine ("D:\wamp\www" etc. in my case, using WAMP on Windows 10, I know, it's not ideal).

Is there any way to generalise this statement so that I don't need two separate paths concatenations? Am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need two because one is a path and the other a URL. But it could be a bit more DRY.

This answer makes use of a handy constant defined in `index.php` - `FCPATH`.
It is the path to the front controller (index.php) directory. Using the constant will make the code more portable, less error prone.

```
$doc_location = "public/mi-corpus/" . $handle . "/file.pdf";
$object_src = base_url($doc_location);
$ocr_src = FCPATH.$doc_location;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Too bad I can't merge the references but this answers my question :)

Answer (score 0):

for $object_src variable you have to used baseurl() function in below format

base_url()."folderpath/file.pdf"

where folderpath is the path from your server root directory say www.

eg. if your server path of pdf file is /var/www/public/mi-corpus/file.pdf and your server root directory is /var/www then your object_src path will be below.

$object_src = base_url()."public/mi-corpus/file.pdf";

I hope this helps you in understanding the problem.

thanks

Comment: I had this working already and I was just wondering if I could merge the paths into one, but thank you.